HttpClientModule is deprecated in Angular 18, what's the replacement?
I have a project I migrated to Angular 18 with a setup to use the HttpClient by importing the HttpClientModule.
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
 ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {} 

In v17 HttpClientModule everything was fine but now it is marked as deprecated.
Why is it deprecated and what is the replacement ?

The HttpClientModule was superseded by the already existing provideHttpClient() provider function.
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // Remove the module 
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
 ],
 providers: [provideHttpClient()] // add it here
 bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {} 

If you see the following error: Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'., it means you were importing the HttpClientModule in a component. This shouldn't have happen in the first place. Simply remove the import.
If you are relying on standalone component, provideHttpClient() needs to be added to the providers when invoking bootstrapApplication() :
boostrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig); 

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    . . .
    provideHttpClient(withFetch())
  ]
};


The reason behind this change is that the HttpClientModule doubled-up the provideHttpClient() function that was introduced for standalone apps.
And here is an extract of the Angular source code, the module was really just providing the HttpClient. (No declarations, imports or export whatsoever)
@NgModule({
  providers: [provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())],
})

export class HttpClientModule {}

So the team chose to deprecate it and the deprecation message suggests to use the provideHttpClient() provider function. This way devs would less be inclined to have both the module and the provider declared. Which was a common issue amongst new developers.

Does not work for me. I'm getting:  TS2322: Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.

You shouldn't have it in a component.

What if there is no AppModule but a standalone AppComponent and a Service that injects an HttpClient? Where to provide the new form of the deprecated HttpClientModule? If I don't provide anything I get an "NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!" and you say provideHttpClient() shouldn't be used in the app component (which leads to the "Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.")

@Simon add it to the providers when calling boostrapApplication

Add this in, app.config.ts file and do not add import of HttpClient or HttpClientModule in app.component.ts.

To use provideHttpClient() it must be imported from '@angular/common/http'

You can also add this app.config.ts file.
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    . . .
    provideHttpClient(withFetch())
  ]
};


Ths is what worked for me and not putting it in the provider inside the local module. The only change I did was to use provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()) instead.

I am using Angular 18 and had same issue . Angular 18 the HttpClientModule  has been deprecated and replaced with a simpler, more efficient method for setting up HTTP services, using function provideHttpClient() Angular Doc.
So you have to remove HttpClientModule from from your module and add provideHttpClient in providers Array.

In Angular18 you can use provideHttpClient()
HttpClient is provided using the provideHttpClient helper function, which most apps include in the application providers in app.config.ts.
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
  ]
};


If you are using angular 18 CLI to create angular projects and components, then there is probably no app.module.ts file. That is because all the components in angular 18 are stand-alone.
All you have to do to fix the issue is add provideHttpClient() to the providers in the app.config.ts file.
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
 providers: [
  provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
  provideRouter(routes),
  provideHttpClient(),
 ],
};


You need to add provideHttpClient() to app.config.ts:


Please do not upload images of code.. Also, there is no additional value in this answer. Other answer has suggested exactly the same.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
